# Showing a ViewController in a ContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I´m trying to show a ViewController in a ContainerView.
If I use a internal ViewController (source in the same project as the ContainerView) it´ll work as expected.
So I´m using a ViewController from another project it won't be shown.
I`ve implemented an AlertDialog in viewDidLoad of the external ViewController and the AlterDialog will be shown.

EDIT:
I found out that I have to add the .xib of the external ViewController, to the Copy Bundle Resouces in Build Phases (In main project).
Is there another way to solve this issue?

Code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Utilities/Form.h"
#import "TestForm.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize ListContainer = _ListContainer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    @try {

        Form *viewConnection = [[Form alloc]init];
        viewConnection.view.frame = _ListContainer.bounds;
        [_ListContainer addSubview:viewConnection.view];
        [self addChildViewController:viewConnection];
        [viewConnection didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
            }
    @finally {


    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

alloc/init is almost always the wrong way to create a view controller. It doesn't provide an XIB file or storyboard containing the view contents. You should probably provide a custom init method in your Form class that you can call that uses `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to create a view controller from the other project's storyboard, or `initWithNibName:bundle:` to create it with a nib.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply but with your solution it won't be shown too. I ask myself why it works if I use the internal Form but if i use the external form it does't work

Comment: "internal form"? "external form"? What do those terms mean?

Comment: The internal form is the viewcontroller inside my main project the external one is the viewcontroller inside the included Framework Project

Comment: Is the framework project yours or was it written by a third party? Is it designed so that you can include it's view controllers as children of other view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!

Like Duncan C mentioned I had to write my own init.

Following Code is the result:

```
//
//  Form.m
//  Utilities

#import "Form.h"

@interface Form ()

@end

@implementation Form

-(id)init
{
    NSBundle* resourcesBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[Form class]];
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"Form" bundle:resourcesBundle];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```